# How to color a board such that each square has exactly two neighbors of the opposite color

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, coloring

Let $m≥2$, $n≥2$ integers. We want to color the squares of an $m × n$ board with black and white so that each square has exactly two neighbors of the other color. Determine all the values ​​of $m$ and $n$ for which it is possible to do such a coloring.
Clarification: Neighboring squares are those that have a common side.

I found a way to color the square when $m$ and $n$ are both even. I think that if $m$ or $n$ is odd, then it is impossible to color de board. But i can't prove it. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Is there a reason for asking for "all values of $m$ and $4n$" rather than simply "all values of $m$ and $n$" ?

Comment: No (sorry, it was a typo)

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Selective of Cono Sur 1999

Comment: Thank you. Took me a bit, but I [found the problems](https://oma.org.ar/enunciados/con10sel.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $m=n$, then $m$ and $n$ are both even or both odd; however, the condition requires an even number of black and white squares, so $mn = m^2$ is even; therefore $m=n$ is even. Now let's deal with rectangles that are not squares. Without loss of generality, $n<m$.

**Lemma.** Assuming $n < m$, the top $n$ rows form an $n\times n$ sub-board symmetric about its main diagonal.

**Proof.** Induct on the anti-diagonals, looking at them in the following order:

```
123456
23456
3456
456 .
56   .
6     .
```

We begin in the middle of each anti-diagonal:

- For the odd anti-diagonals, the middle square can be filled arbitrarily.
- For the even anti-diagonals, the middle two squares are both adjacent to the middle square of the previous anti-diagonal, which (by symmetry) already has two neighbors of one color, so they get the same color.

Then we work outwards, and every step is forced, so the anti-diagonal is symmetric. $\square$

The top $n \times n$ sub-board is symmetric, and its rightmost edge consists of $n$ squares on the edge of the board; its bottom edge (the $n^{\text{th}}$ row of the board), on the other hand, has $n$ squares with more squares below them. However, since the two edges are the same, the coloring condition for them is satisfied just by the $n \times n$ sub-board. Therefore the squares in the $(n+1)^{\text{th}}$ row are identically colored to the squares on the $n^{\text{th}}$ row.

It follows that if we delete the $n \times n$ sub-board, we get an $(m-n)\times n$ board for which the coloring condition also holds.

Now we can finish the claim by induction on the size of the board. The induction hypothesis tells us that both $m-n$ and $n$ must be even; therefore $m$ and $n$ are both even.

Comment: Does your argument prove that each row and column must have equal numbers of black and white squares?

Comment: My argument doesn't prove that (though if you proved this claim for squares, it would give you the same claim for rectangles as a corollary). I do think it's true, and if you can prove it more easily, that would give us a simpler argument for this problem.

Comment: I have no proof, just conjecture.

Comment: Experimentally, it seems like even more is true: if you look at the first (or last) row (or column), it's a sequence of blocks that are either `01` or `10`. Also, every sequence of length $2n$ that's made up of $n$ such blocks can be the side of a $2n \times 2n$ board.

Comment: Experimentally, if an $m\times n$ board is colored black & white so that each square **not on the bottom row** has exactly 2 neighbors of the opposite color, then: if the top row has equal numbers of black and white squares, the same is true for all rows; but if the top row has $m$ black and $n$ white squares where $m\gt n$, then the 2nd row has $m+1$ white and $n-1$ black, the 3rd row has $m+2$ black and $n-2$ white, etc. If so, then the total number of black squares can't equal the total number of white squares, as it would if every sqauare had exactly 2 neighbors of the opposite color.

Comment: Oops. Not exactly. That "experimental observation" was based on *very* little data. Didn't have to look far for a counterexample: $$\begin{matrix}0&1&0&0&1&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a convenient trick: Flip the color of every other square.  I.e. if a square has coordinates $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$, flip it's color if $x+y$ is even.  Then this modified board will be such that every square has two neighbors of the same color.  This means that each square is on a loop of identical color.

Now look at one side of the rectangle, say the bottom.  Each square on the bottom has at least one neighbor of the same color also on the bottom (since it has only one neighbor on the board that's not on the bottom).  I claim the contiguous blocks of same-colored squares on the bottom can only have even length: If a contiguous block of squares $1, 2, \dots, n$ has the same color, say black, then squares $2, 3, \dots, n-1$ must have white neighbors above them (see picture below; grey squares are undetermined by this argument).  Number these white squares $2,3, \dots, n-1$ just like their neighbors below.  Then white squares $3,4,\dots,n-2$ must have black neighbors above them.  And so on inductively until we are left with just 2 squares at positions $n/2, n/2+1$.  This shows you can only have even blocks on the boundary of the board, and hence the boundary itself must have even length, being a sum of possibly several such blocks.  Hence the board must have even dimensions $m$ and $n$.

[image: Even block]

Comment: I think you're missing many possibilities. What about [this 8x8 board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRhBS.png)?

Comment: I agree with your proof that $m,n$ are even, but not the bull's-eye picture you illustrate it with, and not the characterization of all solutions. I believe that an $n \times n$ board has $2^{n/2}$ colorings: if you fill in its first row with `01` and `10` blocks (which corresponds to filling the modified board with `00` and `11` blocks, making sure the property you prove holds), the rest of the board is always filled in a unique way. I (less strongly) believe that an $m\times n$ board has $2^{d/2}$ colorings where $d=\gcd(m,n)$ obtained by tiling a $d\times d$ board and its reflection.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yeah, I agree.  My characterization was wrong, and yours seems to be correct.

Comment: Suggested illustrations: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zLVq.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz8hY.png). The first is a diagram of the portion of the bull's-eye that is forced by the bottom row. The second shows what happens if the monochromatic block at the bottom is odd: we get into a contradiction at the top middle square, which already has three opposite-color neighbors by the time we get to it.